# Select Elements using linq to xml query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Need to capture all the elements from the xml tag OperationName excluding OperationName tag itself i.e.

```
<testdata>
<EPPublicCall>
    <OperationName>
        <server xmlns="http://docs.openstack.org/compute/api/v1.1" imageRef="3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001" flavorRef="2" name="api-test-server-xml2"/>
    </OperationName>
    <OperationType>Public</OperationType>
</EPPublicCall>
```

need to fetch below

```
<server xmlns="http://docs.openstack.org/compute/api/v1.1" imageRef="3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001" flavorRef="2" name="api-test-server-xml2"/>
```

Tried using below query but it's also fetching OperationName which I don't want

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\TestData.xml");
        return
            from vars in doc.Descendants("EPPublicCall")
            let operationName = vars.Elements("OperationName")
            select new object[] { operationName };
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just to clarify - you don't know what result you'll actually get inside the OperationName element, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the direct descendants of `OperationName` without knowing what they are, simple add a call to the `.Elements()` method on the enumerable XElements, with no arguments:

```
return
    from vars in doc.Descendants("EPPublicCall")
    let operationName = vars.Elements("OperationName")
    select new object[] { operationName.Elements() };
```

or, if you want a simpler return object:

```
return doc.Descendants("EPPublicCall").Elements("OperationName").Elements();
```

which will resolve as an `IEnumerable<XElement>` instead of an `IEnumerable<object[]>` containing `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Descendants` method, by specifying the namespace:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://docs.openstack.org/compute/api/v1.1";

var elements = doc.Descendants(ns + "server").ToList();
```